# AWS Cloudfront serving assets over HTTPS

Tags: https, amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I use Amazon Cloudfront as a CDN; portions of my site are protected by HTTPS. Supposedly we should be able to use out Cloudfront sub-domain (`https://HASH.cloudfront.net`) to serve SSL content and the custom CNAME to server HTTP content. *(custom names are coming soon.)*

This seems to work fine for images (no custom configuration), and I can use the Cloudfront URL to serve HTTP requests just fine. **However, when I try to access CSS or JS files... and presumably others.. over HTTPS-- I get: "ERROR Failed to contact the origin."**

- Am I missing a step within the AWS Console to let it know something about my cert?
- Am I missing a configuration within my origin to allow hand-off to the CF domain?

What would seem to be the [primary source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#SecureConnectionsHowToRequire) on this topic isn't very helpful. The documentation just says to have a valid certificate on the origin and set "Origin Protocol Policy" to match viewer. But that sure doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How is the origin configured? custom? s3?

Comment: Origin is a completely separate non-AWS, VPS web host.

Comment: Is there anything that would prevent cloudfront from accessing the css or js files? is there a problem with how the path is mapped?

Comment: No I can reach the assets just fine via the origin, the hashed cloudfront URL on HTTP, and my custom CNAME. Just can't view them over HTTPS.